# How to use pgFouine with PostgreSQL 9.1?

Tags: php, postgresql, profiling, pgfouine

Using pgFouine 1.2, PostgreSQL 9.1.3.

postgresql.conf settings:

```
log_min_duration_statement = 0
log_duration = on
log_line_prefix = '%t [%p]: [%l-1] '
log_statement = 'all'
lc_messages = 'C'           # locale for system error message strings
lc_monetary = 'C'           # locale for monetary formatting
lc_numeric = 'C'            # locale for number formatting
lc_time = 'C'               # locale for time formatting
```

Error I am getting when running pgFouine:

`C:\Users\Razvan\Desktop\pgfouine-1.2>php pgfouine.php -file log > report.html`

```
pgFouine did not find any valid PostgreSQL log line in your log file:
* check that PostgreSQL uses an english locale for logging (lc_messages in your postgresql.conf),
* check that you use the -logtype option (syslog, stderr) according to your log file,
* if you use syslog and log_line_prefix, check that your log_line_prefix has a trailing space,
* if you use stderr, check that your log_line_prefix is of the form '%t [%p]: [%l-1] '.
If you think your log file and your options are correct, please contact the author (gsmet on #postgresql@freenode or guillaume-pg at smet dot org).
```

I am using the log file found in `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.1\data\pg_log`

I tried varied settings but nothing worked and couldn't find any solution on internet either.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you show the first lines of your log file?

Comment: @DanielVérité: Here are a few lines from the beginning of the log file: http://paste2.org/p/2027616

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding the logtype option:

```
pgfouine -logtype stderr -file filename
```

Comment: Where should I add the above code ? In the log file or postgresql.conf file ?

Comment: @Jay: it's a command you type in a shell interpreter. See pgfouine documentation.

Comment: The present command which I am using in the command prompt is php pgfouine.php -file /postgresql/data/pg_log/postgresql-2014-06-24_083518.log > jtest.html
how should I change it ?

Comment: @Jay: you want to ask a new question explaining your case